# MEXT English Exam: "cope with acknowledge"?

Tags: word-choice

I am doing the MEXT English Examination in 2014 ([Questions](http://www.studyjapan.go.jp/pdf/questions/14/ke_en.pdf) | [Answers](http://www.studyjapan.go.jp/pdf/questions/14/ke_answer.pdf)). I encounter this question II. 10. :

> The organization says more than half of depression sufferers are not
> receiving treatment because many (     ) acknowledge their illness.
>
> A. cope with.
>
> B. fail to.
>
> C. hope to.
>
> D. put up with.

I thought the correct answer should be B, but it turns out to be A. I am not an English native speaker so I am not sure what does "cope with acknowledge" imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right, the correct answer should be B. "Cope with acknowledge" is nonsensical.

“Cope with their illness” would make sense, but “cope with acknowledge their illness” does not.

Source: am native speaker.